# Setting col= parameter using par()

Tags: r

I want to illustrate R's `par()` graphics parameter command with multiple graphs, so I did a simple 2×2 layout that's graphed great. I added a single `par (col = "green")` command to cause the one `barplot()` and three `hist()`ograms, but it did nothing that I could see.

Here's my R script, which should be safe since I save and restore your graphics settings at the top and bottom. Apologies for the long `dput()` but I want you to have the data I have.

```r
    savedGraphicsParams <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
    layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))
    par(col = "green") # doesn't work

    attach(Lakes)

    # GRAPH 1:
    barplot(table(N_of_Fish), main="Fish", xlab = "No. of Fish")

    # GRAPH 2:
    hist(Elevation, main = "Elevation", xlab = "ft")

    # GRAPH 3
    hist(Surface_Area, main="Surface Area", xlab = parse(text="ft^2"))

    # GRAPH 4
    hist(`, main="Max Depth", xlab = "ft")

    detach(Lakes)     

par(savedGraphicsParams) # Reset the graphics
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** Unfortunately, as far as I know, you just can't do this; you have to use `col=` in the individual plot calls. Picking through `?par`, we find:

> Several parameters can **only** be set by a call to ‘par()’: ... 
>   The remaining parameters can **also** be set as arguments (often via
>        ‘...’) to high-level plot functions ...
>   **However**, see the comments on ‘bg’, ‘cex’, ‘col’, ‘lty’,
>        ‘lwd’ and ‘pch’ **which may be taken as *arguments* to certain plot
>        functions rather than as graphical parameters**.

(emphasis added).

I interpret this as meaning that `bg` et al. *cannot* be set globally by a call to `par()` (even though they're described and discussed in `?par`), but **must** be set as arguments to individual plotting calls. I would write the code this way (also avoiding the use of `attach()`, which is advised against even in its own manual page ...)

```
plot_col <- "green"
with (Lakes,
 {
  barplot(table(N_of_Fish), main="Fish", xlab = "No. of Fish", col=plot_col)
  hist(Elevation, main = "Elevation", xlab = "ft", col=plot_col)
  hist(Surface_Area, main="Surface Area", xlab = parse(text="ft^2"), col=plot_col)
  hist(Maximum_Depth, main="Max Depth", xlab = "ft", col=plot_col)
 })
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I misinterpreted your bold sentence. When `bg` worked as a global parameter, I thought `col` would as well, especially since all the other col versions worked.

I've read all the arguments on `attach` and `with` and the consensus is not to use them. I think they're both appropriate in short blocks of example code when only one data table is involved, especially if you detach immediately.

Comment: I agree that it's not worth being dogmatic about anything, including `attach()`.  I'm surprised that you say that there's a consensus not to use `with()` though - where did you read that?  If my answer resolves (I won't say "solves") your question, you can click the check-mark to accept it ...

Comment: I’m trying to remember the last R book I read. They’re all the same it seems—nothing that creates local scoping is good. Datatable$Variable is about all that’s approved of in the “literature” these days.

Comment: huh.  Still find that surprising.  Lots of interest in tidyverse (which uses non-standard evaluation to avoid $), but I'd be interested if you can point me to a source that deprecates `with()` ...

Comment: Deprecates? I have no source. Just recommendations.

Comment: By "deprecates" I simply mean "advocates not using" (or, quoting your previous comment, says that "nothing that creates local scoping is good". The usual advice (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242904/problems-with-attach-in-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797797/attach-inside-function/5800785#5800785) is to use `with()`.  But maybe I'm out of date/out of touch - that's why I'm curious where you're finding the recommendations to avoid local scoping at all costs ...

Comment: I can't find the source, and I've looked all afternoon. I'll start going with with() as the official good news.

Comment: I was hoist by my own with statement today, as I used it as a shortcut to generate a sheet full of diagnostic plots from the same data set. Later, I needed one of the return values of that function, and couldn’t (for the moment) get it, because I forget that with() groups, but also locally scopes.